# When number hits a certain reach it gets back to the previous number

Tags: javascript, jquery

This is what happens: [gif](https://gfycat.com/lankypleasedanura)(Take a look at the gif to better understanding). You can see that when number hits 2 it comes back to 1 and when it hits 4 it comes back to 3... That doesn't happen in a  orderly way, from number 4 upwards it might reach number 10 or over without getting back to previous number. I think this is somewhat related to the reload of the page. Could someone explain why this is happening? Also, how can the code be changed in order to work properly?

This is the complete code:

```
<?php
session_start();
?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <title>Carrinho</title>
    <script src="https://kit.fontawesome.com/3da1a747b2.js"></script>
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Catamaran&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/5.11.2/css/all.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="semantic/dist/semanticModificado.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="payment.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="cart.css">
    <style>

    </style>
</head>

<body>
    <div class="container" id="navmobile" style="display: none">
        <img src="upload\felinefilogo.svg" style="margin-top: 1rem" height="100px" width="250px" alt="">
        <img src="upload\felinefi.svg" height="20px" width="62.5px" alt="">
        <nav class="navbar" style="padding: 0; margin-right: 16px">
            <ul class="nav">
                <li><a href="#home">Início</a></li>
                <li><a href="#about">Sobre</a></li>
                <li><a href="contact.php">Contato</a></li>
                <li><a href="cart2.php" display="none" class="nav-item nav-link active">
                        <h5 class="px-5 cart" style="display: flex;">
                            &nbsp;Carrinho&nbsp;
                            <span id="cart-item" class="cart-item text-warning bg-light"></span> &nbsp;
                            <i class="fas fa-shopping-cart fa-flip-horizontal" aria-hidden="true"></i>
                        </h5>
                    </a></li>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </nav>
    </div>

    <nav class="navbar" id="navdesktop">
        <div class="container">
            <div class="imagem"><img src="upload\felinefihorizontalmedium.svg" height="100px" width="250px" alt="">
            </div>
            <ul class="nav">
                <li><a href="index2.php">Início</a></li>
                <li><a href="#about">Sobre</a></li>
                <li><a href="contact.php">Contato</a></li>
                <li><a href="cart2.php" display="none" class="nav-item nav-link active">
                        <h5 class="px-5 cart" style="display: flex;">
                            &nbsp;Carrinho&nbsp;
                            <span id="cart-item" class="cart-item text-warning bg-light"> </span> &nbsp;
                            <i class="fas fa-shopping-cart fa-flip-horizontal" aria-hidden="true"></i>
                        </h5>
                    </a></li>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </nav>
    <section class="section-aPayment">
        <div class="containerPayment">
            <div class="row" style="flex-wrap:nowrap" !important>
                <div class="col-75">
                    <br>
                    <h2 class="meuCarrinho">Meu carrinho</h2>
                    <br>
                    <form action="">
                        <?php
                        require 'config.php';
                        $stmt = $conn->prepare("SELECT * FROM cart");
                        $stmt->execute();
                        $result = $stmt->get_result();
                        $grand_total = 0;
                        while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) :
                            ?>
                            <div class="cartContainer">
                                <div class="sub-container">
                                    <div class="imagem2"><img src="<?= $row['product_image'] ?>" alt=""></div>
                                    <div class="conteudodaDiv">
                                        <div class="title-e-icon">
                                            <h3><?= $row['product_name'] ?></h3> <!-- <button class="icon" name="remove"> --><a href="action.php?remove=<?= $row['id'] ?>"><i class="fas fa-trash-alt"></i></a>
                                        </div>
                                        <p>Ref: <span># D12-9970-014-39</span></p>
                                        <p>Vendido por <a href="index2.php">Felinefi</a> e entregue em até 8 dias úteis. </p>
                                        <p>Frete GRÁTIS</p>
                                        <p>Tamanho: <span>39 </span></p>
                                        <p>Cor: <span>Preto</span> </p>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                                <hr>
                                <div class="eita">
                                    <h1>Quantidade:&nbsp;&nbsp;
                                        <button type="button" class="ui circular button" id="menos"><svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="24" height="24" viewBox="-5 -15 39 39">
                                                <path d="M12 2c5.514 0 10 4.486 10 10s-4.486 10-10 10-10-4.486-10-10 4.486-10 10-10zm0-2c-6.627 0-12 5.373-12 12s5.373 12 12 12 12-5.373 12-12-5.373-12-12-12zm6 13h-12v-2h12v2z" />
                                            </svg></button>
                                        <div class="ui mini icon input focus">
                                            <input class="itemQty" value="<?= $row['qty'] ?>" type="text" style="padding-right: 8px; padding-left: 12px; width: 34px;" minlength="1" disabled="">
                                            <input type="hidden" class="pid" value="<?= $row['id'] ?>">
                                            <input type="hidden" class="pprice" value="<?= $row['product_price'] ?>">
                                        </div>
                                        <button type="button" class="ui circular button" id="mais"><svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="24" height="24" viewBox="-5 -15 39 39">
                                                <path d="M12 2c5.514 0 10 4.486 10 10s-4.486 10-10 10-10-4.486-10-10 4.486-10 10-10zm0-2c-6.627 0-12 5.373-12 12s5.373 12 12 12 12-5.373 12-12-5.373-12-12-12zm6 13h-5v5h-2v-5h-5v-2h5v-5h2v5h5v2z" />
                                            </svg></button>
                                    </h1>
                                    <div class="price">
                                        <span>R$ 79.90</span><span>R$ <?= number_format($row['product_price'], 2) ?></span>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                    </form>
                    <?php $grand_total += $row['total_price']; ?>

                </div>
                <div class="col-25">
                    <br>
                    <h2>Resumo da compra</h2>
                    <br>
                    <div class="containerResumo">
                        <div class="subCoEsquerda1">
                            <h3 class="esquerda">Itens</h3>
                            <h3 class="direita2">(<?= $row['qty'] ?>)</h3>
                        </div>
                        <div>
                            <hr>
                        </div>
                        <div class="subCoDireita2">
                            <h3 class="esquerda">Desconto</h3>
                            <h3 class="direita2" id="hidethisDiv"> 50% </h3>
                        </div>
                        <div>
                            <hr>
                        </div>
                        <div class="subCoEsquerda3">
                            <h3 class="esquerda">Valor total</h3>
                            <h3 class="direita2">R$ <?= number_format($grand_total, 2); ?></h3>
                        </div>
                        <hr>
                        <div class="subCoEsquerda4">
                            <a href="payment2.php"><button class="positive fluid ui button">Continuar</button></a>
                        </div>
                    <?php endwhile; ?>
                    <!-- <h1 class="">The cart is empty</h1> -->
                    <div class="emptycart <?= ($grand_total >= 1) ? 'hideThis' : 'showThis' ?>">
                        <div class="emptycartLogo">
                            <svg data-v-4f460278="" width="100%" height="100%" viewBox="0 0 49 41" version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink">
                                <title data-v-4f460278="">45A0D541-4F15-4397-B2BF-FDEC4E95BD82</title>
                                <desc data-v-4f460278="">Created with sketchtool.</desc>
                                <defs data-v-4f460278=""></defs>
                                <g data-v-4f460278="" id="2019-v2" stroke="none" stroke-width="1" fill="none" fill-rule="evenodd" stroke-linecap="round" stroke-linejoin="round">
                                    <g data-v-4f460278="" id="Vazio" transform="translate(-696.000000, -112.000000)" stroke="#5A2D82">
                                        <g data-v-4f460278="" id="Ícones-/-Interface-/-Carrinho" transform="translate(689.000000, 102.000000)">
                                            <path data-v-4f460278="" id="Stroke-1" d="M8.23136646,11.5266391 L12.7109627,11.5266391
            L23.9470186,42.3026466
              L48.5837391,42.3026466 M15.4262547,17.1737669
              L54.8276398,17.1737669 L54.8276398,30.1021654
              L22.6169068,36.6555188" stroke-width="1.5"></path>
                                            <path data-v-4f460278="" id="Stroke-3" d="M16.6547019,23.3746992 L54.8276398,23.3746992
            L16.6547019,23.3746992 Z M31.341,47.0078872 C31.341,48.6126617
            30.0257143,49.9090677 28.4054348,49.9090677 C26.7893913,49.9090677
            25.4762236,48.6126617 25.4762236,47.0078872 C25.4762236,45.401015
            26.7893913,44.104609 28.4054348,44.104609
            C30.0257143,44.104609 31.341,45.401015 31.341,47.0078872
            L31.341,47.0078872 Z M46.3937143,47.0078872 C46.3937143,48.6126617
            45.0805466,49.9090677 43.4602671,49.9090677 C41.8421056,49.9090677
            40.5289379,48.6126617 40.5289379,47.0078872 C40.5289379,45.401015
            41.8421056,44.104609 43.4602671,44.104609 C45.0805466,44.104609
            46.3937143,45.401015 46.3937143,47.0078872 L46.3937143,47.0078872 Z" stroke-width="0.972"></path>
                                        </g>
                                    </g>
                                </g>
                            </svg>
                        </div>
                        <div class="emptycartTitle">
                            Seu carrinho está vazio.
                        </div>
                        <div class="emptycartTe">
                            Adicione o produto clicando no botão “Adqurir” na página de produto.
                        </div>
                        <div class="emptycartButton">
                            <button onclick="location.href= 'index2.php'" class="ui grey basic button">VOLTAR PARA A PÁGINA INICIAL</button>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </section>

    <script src=" https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.4.1.min.js" integrity="sha256-CSXorXvZcTkaix6Yvo6HppcZGetbYMGWSFlBw8HfCJo=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery.mask/1.14.16/jquery.mask.min.js"></script>
    <script src="semantic/dist/semantic.min.js"></script>

    <script>
        $("input[name='expyear']").mask("00 / 00");
        $("input[name='zip']").mask("00000 - 000");
    </script>

    <script>
        //a condição surte efeito quando a página da reload ou aperta f5.
        $(document).ready(function() {
            if ($(this).width() < 500) {

                $('#navdesktop').hide();
                $('#navmobile').show();

            } else if ($(this).width() > 500) {

                $('#navmobile').hide();
                $('#navdesktop').show();

            }
        });
        //a condição surte efeito apenas quando mexe na "responsividade" da página.
        $(window).resize(function() {

            if ($(this).width() < 500) {

                $('#navdesktop').hide();
                $('#navmobile').show();

            } else if ($(this).width() > 500) {

                $('#navmobile').hide();
                $('#navdesktop').show();

            }

        });
    </script>

    <script>
        //aumentar e diminuir a quantidade dos itens (respectivamente).
        $(function() {
            $('#mais').on('click', function() {
                var $quantidade = $(this).closest('h1').find('.itemQty');
                var currentVal = parseInt($quantidade.val());
                if (!isNaN(currentVal)) {
                    $quantidade.val(currentVal + 1);
                    $(".itemQty").trigger('change');
                }
            });
            $('#menos').on('click', function() {
                var $quantidade = $(this).closest('h1').find('.itemQty');
                var currentVal = parseInt($quantidade.val());
                if (!isNaN(currentVal) && currentVal > 0) {
                    $quantidade.val(currentVal - 1);
                    $(".itemQty").trigger('change');
                }
            });
        });
    </script>

    <script>
        //ajax.
        $(document).ready(function() {

            $(".itemQty").on('change', function() {
                var $el = $(this).closest('div');

                var pid = $el.find(".pid").val();
                var pprice = $el.find(".pprice").val();
                var qty = $el.find(".itemQty").val();
                location.reload(true);

                $.ajax({
                    url: 'action.php',
                    method: 'post',
                    cache: false,
                    data: {
                        qty: qty,
                        pid: pid,
                        pprice: pprice,
                    },
                    success: function(response) {
                        console.log(response);
                    }
                });
            });

            load_cart_item_number();

            function load_cart_item_number() {
                $.ajax({
                    url: 'action.php',
                    method: 'get',
                    data: {
                        cartItem: "cart-item"
                    },
                    success: function(response) {
                        $('.cart-item').html(response);
                    }
                });
            }
        });
    </script>

    <script type='text/javascript'>
        //mostra o conteúdo do carrinho quando a página carrega depois de clicar em "Adicionar ao Carrinho".
        window.onload = function() {
            if (!window.location.hash) {
                window.location = window.location + '#loaded';
                window.location.reload();
            }
        }
    </script>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Can you reproduce the problem in a [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/) or [codepen](https://codepen.io)? This example has way to much data/code we don't need to reproduce the problem.

Comment: @Refilon It has some php in it(I get the value over php) but the problem itself is about javascript only

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is because you are using the `h1` that you reload each time with ajax as a source of truth. To increase the number, sometimes once you click the page it still has not reloaded so it picks the older value.

As a recommendation I would set a variable outside of the minus and mais function in js that keeps track of the current amount of items like this ( Where number of items comes from the PHP first load ).

```
let current = <?= $number_of_items ?>;
```

Comment: Sorry but how would that be? could you explain in more detail so I can put it in the code? I put the variable and then I do what?

Comment: I declared a variable like this: <?php $number_of_items += $row['qty']; ?> which is inside a while loop, and the I declared the variable you said outside of the minus and mais function... but it is giving me an error...